# How do you convert regular grammar into finite automata: S->aaB|aB|epsolon, B->bb|bS|aBB

Tags: regex, complexity-theory, regular-language, computation-theory, finite-automata

How to deal with aaB and aB.on getting aa input i make three state including start state.Can i again add one more transition from start state on geting a lead to state B? or i have to do something else?

Comment: the question is illegible. Can you explain what you want please ?

Comment: Can you explain your expected result by example ??

Comment: I think it's _epsilon_.

Comment: This question is difficult to understand. Please provide a clear EBNF or BNF grammar, with "epsilon" correctly spelled, with spaces between each symbol. If your grammar is `S -> a a B | a B | ; B -> b b | b S | a B B ;`, the grammar is NOT regular.

Answer (score 0):

For this Question first we need know about the Regular Grammar

Regula Grammar also known as Type-3 Grammar.

Regular grammar generates regular language. They have a single non-terminal on the left-hand side and a right-hand side consisting of a single terminal or single terminal followed by a non-terminal.

The productions must be in the form:

```
  A ⇢ xB 
  A ⇢ x
  A ⇢ Bx
where A, B ∈ Variable(V) and x ∈ T*  i.e. string of terminals.
```

Types of regular grammar:

1. Left linear grammar(LLG):
   In LLG, the productions are in the form if all the productions are of the form

   ```
    A ⇢ Bx
    A ⇢ x
    where A,B ∈ V and x ∈ T*
   ```
2. Right linear grammar(RLG):
   In RLG, the productions are in the form if all the productions are of the form

   ```
    A ⇢ xB
    A ⇢ x
   where A,B  ∈ V and x ∈ T*
   ```

The language generated by type-3 grammar is a regular language, for which a FA can be designed. The FA can also be converted into type-3 grammar

The given grammar is Right linear grammar.

[image of Finite Automata from Regular Grammar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aT4B.jpg)

As there are two variables we need to create two states.
and make S as final state.